# Maximum allowed cache in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, safari

I am working on a web-application which has **multiple videos sizing upto 22MBs**.
The requirement is to cache these videos or store it in local-storage so as to avoid buffering of the videos every-time the end-user hits the website on iPad.

Is it valid to do such thing ?
I need a suggestion to check if this practice is good to use such large amount of memory for video caching in iPad ?

(The application is majorly accessed through the safari on iPad or iOS)

Comment: Just be sure you follow the "data storage guidelines".  (Of course, interpreting them takes an Ouija board, but welcome to the club.)

Comment: @HotLicks Hey thanks, can u also provide me with the official / authorized link where i can get these guidelines ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/ , but you've got to sign in with your "developer ID".

Comment: And storing something on iCloud is totally different than storing something on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about best practices for video since I haven't done much with video, but if you're looking for information about how much data you can hold and how, check out http://milesmatthias.com/post/21323839252/the-current-state-of-client-side-storage for a summary of the different tactics and their size limits.